# Complex XML structure for inserting records (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to write to XML file with complex structure.

My valid xml structure is like following.

```
  <ads>
<ad id="00121" date="1/1/2016 01:01:59"  >
    <adinfo title="" email="" phone="" rOD="" rPrice="" rat="" cdetails="" address="" postal="" />
    <adimg>
        <img mail="T" src=""/>
        <img mail="F" src=""/>
        <img mail="F" src=""/>
    </adimg>
</ad>

<ad id="00121" date="1/1/2016 01:01:59"  >
    <adinfo title="" email="" phone="" rOD="" rPrice="" rat="" cdetails="" address="" postal="" />
    <adimg>
        <img mail="T" src=""/>
        <img mail="F" src=""/>
        <img mail="F" src=""/>
    </adimg>
</ad>

....
....
</ads>
```

I have read this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

But above tutorial is for simple XML structure.

As you can see my XML is bit complex.

For example I need to insert `ad` inside parent `ads` element

What should I use and how I can approach to solving this problem?

thnx

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack (works for xml)

Answer (score 1):

Use `functional construction` approach to create new elements; Its very easy and you can create any type of complex elements with this technique.

**Convert string XML to XDocument**

```
    xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
   //xml contains string value of XML
```

**Create new XElement**

```
XElement xElement = new XElement("ad", 
                new XAttribute("id", 00121), 
                new XAttribute("date", "1/1/2016 01:01:59"),                    
                 new XElement ("adinfo", 
                     new XAttribute("title", ""),
                     new XAttribute("phone", "")
                     //Add more attributes
                    ),
                    new XElement("adimg", 
                    new XElement("img", 
                        new XAttribute("mail", "F")
                        //Add more attributes
                        )
                    //Add more XElements
                    )                    
                );
```

**Add newly created XElement To Document Root Element**

```
 xDoc.Element("ads").Add(xElement);
```

**Save To File**

```
xDoc.Save("xmlFile.xml");
```

--SJ